# Pass integer instead of resource color

Tags: java, android, colors, dialog, android-resources

I am using a [library](https://github.com/javiersantos/MaterialStyledDialogs) to show some nice dialogs. I now came to the point where I am getting crashes. If I pass a resource (Eg. R.color.thatRedColor), the dialog will have a red background color. When I am passing an Integer (as it should be used), the app just crashes.. Is there any way that I can pass a valid value using an Integer?

The used line in my colors.xml

```
<color name="indigo">#3f51b5</color>
```

My code

```
int primaryColor = 11243910;

new MaterialStyledDialog(context)
    .setHeaderColor() //If I pass R.color.indigo, it works. If I pass primaryColor, it crashes..
    .setDescription("Hello")
    .setPositive("Ok", new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
            //Do something
        }
    })
    .setNegative("No", new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
            //Don't do anything
        }
    })

    .withDivider(false)
    .show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the source code, use `setHeaderColorInt()`, not `setHeaderColor()`, to pass an actual color value instead of a color resource ID.

In case you get a package clash, add the following:

```
compile ('com.github.javiersantos:MaterialStyledDialogs:1.5.5') {
    exclude group: 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs';
}
```